# file_create_url printing different addresses on live and local installations

Tags: files, uri

I'm using the following code to print out the path of an image uploaded through theme-settings.php:

```
<img src="<?php print file_create_url(file_build_uri(theme_get_setting('my_setting')); ?>" />
```

Locally, everything works fine -- the path renders as I expected:

```
http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/image.jpg
```

When the site is online, however, the same code renders the following address:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/sites/default/files/public%3A//image.jpg
```

Does anyone know why public:// would be printed out on a live server but not on a local installation? My guess is that the problem is related to the use of file_build_uri.

I'd like to find some code that prints out the URL correctly on both live and local installs. Perhaps I'm not using the best approach with the API to achieve this end?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked on both the local and live install:

```
<?php print file_create_url(theme_get_setting('my_setting')); ?>
```